# Adding and removing watermarks from PDFs

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf

We want to add our company's watermark to pdf files (that are uploaded by users).

We found a couple PHP libraries for manipulating PDFs. We're currently using [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/). It appears fairly straight-forward to *add* the watermark, but we're struggling to figure out how to *remove* it.

Is this a limitation of this library? Or is there a more general issue with PDFs that makes this difficult?

Comment: PDF watermarks are not entities in their own right. They are images or writings which merely happen to have the actual content printed over them.

Comment: Thanks. We understand this much. How does this answer my question?

Comment: It depends on how they are added. Is the watermark a vector element on top or below the PDF content? If so, and the PDF is not locked against editing, it should be removable - you'd need a low-level PDF parser to rebuild the document, omitting the watermark. However if the content is made up of images with watermarks drawn on top, they're essentially not removable.

Comment: We can use images or text/vector. It's just our logo and contact information. Since we'll be doing the adding, we can do it however we want. So far it sounds like a vector on top of the pdf content is the best way to go.

Comment: Oh I see, you're adding what you're taking off; I thought you were adding a watermark to some, and removing someone else's mark from others. Righto. Well, the best way is to store the PDF in a non-watermarked form, so that there's no need to remove it. Yes, you can put a vector shape over your PDF, but bear in mind that since it is removable for you, other people can remove it too.

Comment: @halfer We're leaning toward storing multiple iterations (original + watermarked). Seems easiest. However, if we did ever need to add/remove a vector layer in a PDF, could you give us some guidance on how that might work.

Comment: @halfer What tool would you suggest to manage this type of work? I've worked with FPDF and is does not seem to offer a way to achieve the vector shape management you are talking about. I'm interested in the approach you are talking about.

Comment: @Emerson, [maybe TCPDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975072/php-pdf-generator-supporting-vector-images)? Not really done this stuff, so it would require some experimentation - load the PDF in, and draw on top of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used for basic manipulation FPDF, but once I tried a little bit the java itext library it's pretty awesome. And really I recommend to you further reading iText in action. Just give a try through the vogella tutorial. The time you take for this will be really improve yourself.

Specially you can use the PdfStamper for this purpose. I can share a basic usage in https://github.com/web20opensource/stamper

In something similar way like adding a new layer to a image, it's the same way for manipulation pdfs.... you're adding a new layer. And as the same happens in images you can't remove a layer after you have merged all the layers.

Comment: We ended up using pdfStamper also. It was a little tricky for us to set up at first, but once we figured it out it works very well. Their support is very good too.

Comment: Great! Just follow Bruno Lowagie somewhere, the creator of iText